# While importing data from excel in the controller how to check if the specific column exists in the excel file or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I am adding data into my database table through a controller function that is adding the data successfully. The problem is that i have to add data from two different excel files that contain same columns except one column so while adding data i want to put some check in the controller while reading from excel file that whether a specific column exists in excel file or not?
here is my controller method which is working fine for the rest of the columns:

```
using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE COCoreMembers");
    DataAccess.DataTable abc = DataAccess.DataTable.New.ReadCsv(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/TempBrdcepPSC/PscData/co_members.csv"));
    COCoreMember xyz = new COCoreMember();

    foreach (Row Row in abc.Rows)
    {
        xyz._URI = Row["_URI"];
        xyz._PARENT_AURI = Row["_PARENT_AURI"];
        xyz.HHID = Row["HHID"];
        xyz.HHNAME = Row["HHNAME"];
        xyz.HH_SET_ID = Row["HH_SET_ID"];
        xyz.HH_SET_NAME = Row["HH_SET_NAME"];
        xyz.MEM_ID = Row["MEM_ID"];
        xyz.MEM_NAME = Row["MEM_NAME"];
        xyz.MEMBER_AGE = Row["MEMBER_AGE"];
        xyz.POSITION = Row["POSITION"];
        xyz.CELL = Row["CELL"];
        if (Row["CNIC"].ToString() == xyz.CNIC)
        {
            xyz.CNIC = Row["CNIC"];
        }
        else
        {
            xyz.CNIC = "no record";
        }

        //xyz.CNIC = "CNIC";

        db.COCoreMembers.Add(xyz);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I just want to check that if column "CNIC" exists in the excel file then input that into table other wise input "No Record" into its place in the table.

Comment: Try using [`DataColumnCollection.Contains()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumncollection.contains.aspx)  method. I think it will satisfy your requirement.

Comment: One question, is `DataAccess.DataTable` your custom class?

Comment: no i am using DataAccess library

Comment: So this `DataTable` is custom class, not [`.NET DataTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx) class?

Comment: no its not custom class its .net class

Comment: If so then DataTable does not contains `Row` property AFAIK, that you have defined in `foreach (Row Row in abc.Rows) { }`, it should be `foreach (DataRow Row in abc.Rows) { ... }`

Comment: DataColumnCollection.Contains() this method checks for columns in the data base i have to check it in excel file if it exists ther eor not.

Comment: `DataColumnCollection.Contains()` checks column presence in DataTable, not database. Please read its [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumncollection.contains.aspx)

Comment: And you are loading your CSV file into a datatable, so you need to check that column in datatable.

Comment: no i have that column in datatable i have to check in excel file if records against it are present in excel file than add data into that column of the table otherwise add null.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this-

```
using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE COCoreMembers");
    DataAccess.DataTable abc = DataAccess.DataTable.New.ReadCsv(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/TempBrdcepPSC/PscData/co_members.csv"));
    bool checkColumn = false;
    if(abc.Columns.Contains("CNIC"))
    {
        checkColumn = true;
    }
    else
    {
        abc.Columns.Add("CNIC");
    }

    COCoreMember xyz = new COCoreMember();

    foreach (Row Row in abc.Rows)
    {
        xyz._URI = Row["_URI"];
        xyz._PARENT_AURI = Row["_PARENT_AURI"];
        xyz.HHID = Row["HHID"];
        xyz.HHNAME = Row["HHNAME"];
        xyz.HH_SET_ID = Row["HH_SET_ID"];
        xyz.HH_SET_NAME = Row["HH_SET_NAME"];
        xyz.MEM_ID = Row["MEM_ID"];
        xyz.MEM_NAME = Row["MEM_NAME"];
        xyz.MEMBER_AGE = Row["MEMBER_AGE"];
        xyz.POSITION = Row["POSITION"];
        xyz.CELL = Row["CELL"];

        if(checkColumn)
        {
            xyz.CNIC = Row["CNIC"];
        }
        else
        {
            xyz.CNIC = "no record";
        }

        db.COCoreMembers.Add(xyz);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```